# load last viewed page on chrome extension startup

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, session-storage

I'm developing my first chrome extension and I'm stuck with a "session restore" problem. At the begging of the developement when a user log in to my extension and close the popup, when he open the plugin again he had to login again.

I've used [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to be able to save the session infomation to make the user to be still logged in and if he close the plugin, and his session is still active he will be redirected to the welcome page. But how can I check at the extension's startup in what page of the plugin the user was and bring him back to that page?

For example, if a user is logged and was on the "choose a book" section, how can i make the plugin open at "choose a book" section and not in "welcome" section?

Angular 2 for client side
NodeJs for server side

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the session object is something like:

```js
{
   logged: true,
   last_section: 'books'
}
```

When the user visits the books section, save it.

```js
// this code goes inside some listener for visiting a section 
chrome.storage.sync.get('session', function (items) {
  const session = items.session || {}
  session.last_section = 'books'
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ session })
})
```

At the beginning of the popup script, you can simply call `chrome.storage.sync.get` to get the last session object state.

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get('session', function (items) {
   const session = items.session

   if (session && session.logged) {
      if (session.last_section === 'books') {
        // render books section
      }

      if (session.last_section === 'welcome') {
        // render welcome section
      }
   }
})
```